# Android Studio/Gradle BuildConfig in wrong package

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm quite new to Android Studio and Gradle (used Eclipse to build Android Apps). Now I'm having troubles getting Build Variants working. I have a common part with code, resources, manifest and two Variants (again code, resources and manifest). When building one variant I'm getting compilation errors like "cannot find symbol class `BuildConfig`" and "cannot find symbol class `R`" in my variants classes. The variants classes with the errors are referring to `BuildConfig` and `R` from the package of the variant: `de.danielkasstner.wissensapp.saf.BuildConfig` for example. But they get generated in `de.danielkastner.wissensapp` during build process.

Am I missing something fundemantal? Here is my build.gradle (only important part, I think):

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "de.danielkastner.wissensapp"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 21
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }

    hockeyapp {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    saf {
        applicationId "de.danielkastner.wissensapp.saf"
        versionCode 14
        versionName "1.0.2"
    }

    mola {
        applicationId "de.danielkastner.wissensapp.mola"
        versionCode 25
        versionName "0.6.5"
    }
}
```

Comment: Problems of this type are frequently caused by an error in your resources, which causes the R file to not get properly built. Make sure there isn't a resource error somewhere, usually in one of your resource XML files.

Comment: All files look good. I tried the following: created an layout XML file containing an TextView with an id in the variant saf. So it should be only available in 'de.danielkasstner.wissensapp.saf.R', right? But it found it in 'de.danielkasstner.wissensapp.R'.

Comment: There aren't enough details in your question to tell. You'll need to say more about how you're defining your variant-specific resources and what precise errors you're seeing.

Comment: I'm defining variant-specific resources for example in an layout XML in the appropriate folder (src/saf/res/layout). The error I'm seeing is during build process in the compiler/gradle log and it says: "cannot find symbol class R" or "cannot find symbol class BuidlConfig" while it's referring to "de.danielkastner.wissensapp.saf.R".